# spring data binding from POST request to Model

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to understand the concept of binding data from the POST to the model. I want to know whether we can have a control over how the binding is happening. I guess we can control the binding parameters using registering custom editors. But I want to have a finer control over the individual fields of the form. I mean when we register a custom editor, say for date, then all the instances of the, say date, will be treated the same. But may be I want to treat a particular date differently from the others. Moreover, I want to get the POST request parameters in raw string format and may be manipulate one or two fields and delegate the rest to the spring. I guess in the pre-annotation version of spring there was the provision of similar control for some method, may be processFormSubmission. So please let me know whether we can accomplish this in spring 3 annotation version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the format of Date's you can use the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation. The annotation is specified on each field, so each field can have it's own format.

You can format and convert whatever fields you want using `Formatter` and `ConversionService`.

The documentation on all this can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans).